# Problem after PyCharm installation: The ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, spyder

I have just installed the JetBrains' PyCharm so it made some changes on my Anaconda navigator apps namely Spyder and Jupyter Lab. So python code cannot either run or debug on Jupyter and error occurring while Spyder getting started. If anybody helps me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problem comes normally when you updates IDEs or install new related IDEs.

Quick and Temporary Fix:

Enter the following command in anaconda prompt before starting spyder.

set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWpQy.png (Image reference)

Permanent Solution:

Open run.. then paste following path **C:\Windows\System32** then hit enter
where you have to search like **libiomp5md.dll**

Remove it OR Rename it to **libiomp5md.dll.bak.**